# Google Tagging warnings in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, google-tag-manager, google-ads-api, reactjs-flux

Hi I have added the google tag for google tracking and I get the below warnings with a blue color on the Google Tag Assitant with reactjs component

1. update to script based tracking
2. conversion value should be prefixed with standard currency
3. non standard implementation

Also it fires two calls one from the default conversion id and other with my conversion id.

My code is

```
var srcUrl = '//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1111111/?value=10.0&currency_code=USD&label=edfd@#$SDAS32&guid=ON&script=0';


<img height="1" width="1" border="0" src={srcUrl} ></img>
```

Please advice do I need to fix these warnings or can I leave as it is.. Its not showing green because of these warnings.

Comment: Can you please add screenshot how did you add this tracking?  I guess i know how to fix this error, i just need to understand how did you achieve it

Comment: I have a stateless reactjs component and I just created the srcUrl and pasted the url in the src of the img tag.. Thats all

Comment: Blue in Tag Assistant does not mean this won't work, it just means you are not following Googles recommendations. IMO sending an image should work fine for conversion tracking, so the only issue that needs fixing would be point two from the list of issues.